# Use workspace location in the post build script in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the artifacts created in the workspace post jenkins build in a postbuild shell script.

I am not able to use them as workspace artifacts are automatically getting deleted before it comes postbuild script.

Could anyone help me to address this?

Answer (score 0):

When the post-build stage is running, your workspace is already removed. When you think of it, your regular stage and post-build stage may even be running on different nodes, so there can't be any expectation that the files are in your workspace.

To access your artifacts in the post-build stage, you need to fetch them manually, e.g. by using [Copy Artifact plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/):

```
    post {
        always {
            // fetch artifacts of this job and this number to $WORKSPACE
            step([
                $class: 'CopyArtifact',
                filter: '*',
                fingerprintArtifacts: true,
                optional: true,
                projectName: "${JOB_NAME}",
                selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector',
                            buildNumber: "${BUILD_NUMBER}"]
            ])

            script {
                try {
                    for(file in findFiles(glob: "*")) {
                        println "Found file ${file}"
                    }
                } catch(error) {
                    println "Failed to find files"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```